# Java program to create a Descending Order using bucket sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, big-o

I was making a program to take 10 user input values(1-100) and use bucket sort to sort it according to the user preference whether by ascending or descending order. I was able to create the ascending order. This is my code for ascending, but how  could I make it descending?

```
 public class BucketSort{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 public  void bucketSort(int array[], int numBuckets){
  
  System.out.println("Choose Sorting Order:");
  System.out.println("[A] Ascending \n[D] Descending \n Enter choice: ");
  char choice2 = in.next().charAt(0);
    
  
    
  if (choice2 == 'A') {
    List<Integer>[] buckets = new List[numBuckets];
    System.out.println("The user inputted values are " + Arrays.toString(array));
    System.out.println("Algorithm choice is Bucket Sort");
    System.out.println("The sorting order choice is Ascending");
      // Creates empty buckets
for(int i =0; i < numBuckets; i++){
        
        buckets[i] = new LinkedList<>();
    
 }
for(int num: array){
     buckets[hash(num, numBuckets)].add(num);
  }
for(List<Integer> bucket :buckets) {
       Collections.sort(bucket);
 }
 int i = 0;
       for(List <Integer> bucket : buckets) {
           for (int num: bucket){
               array[i++] = num;
    }
}
 }
 private static int hash(int num, int numBuckets) {
   return num/numBuckets;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

`Collections.sort(bucket, Collections.reverseOrder());`

Keep in mind that you have to reverse the order of the buckets when you combine them into the array:

```
for(int index = buckets.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    for (int num: buckets[index]){
       array[i++] = num;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that before but it wasn't really working. I tried 12 13  14 15  21 1 4  6 8 4 as my input value, and the result was 8 6 4 4  1 15 14 13 12 21.

Comment: that's because you have 3 buckets, but each of them is sorted in the reverse order: (8 6 4 4 1) (15 14 13 12) (21), try to combine the buckets into the array starting from the last bucket